# My question is about exportdump with a query on oracle 9i

Tags: oracle

I am getting the following error and i need help.

```
    hcp7 (spar)/tmp $ exp system/puppy parfile=rr.prm                                  


    Export: Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production on Thu Oct 31 13:27:11 2019                 


Copyright (c) 1982, 2002, Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.                


Connected to: Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0 - 64bit Production     
With the Partitioning, OLAP and Oracle Data Mining options                         
JServer Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production                                             
Export done in US7ASCII character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set            

About to export specified tables via Conventional Path ...                         
Current user changed to AHS                                                        
. . exporting table            HB_CONTROL_OUT_DATA                                 
EXP-00056: ORACLE error 933 encountered                                            
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended                                          
Export terminated successfully with warnings.                                      
hcp7 (spar)/tmp $                     


hcp7 (spar)/tmp $ vi rr.prm                                                                                                         
"rr.prm" 6 lines, 258 characters                                                                                                    
file=raj.dmp                                                                                                                        
log=raj.log                                                                                                                         
STATISTICS=none                                                                                                                     
compress=y                                                                                                                          
tables=AHS.HB_CONTROL_OUT_DATA                                                                                                      
query="[select * from hb_control_out_data where exists (select '1' from hb_control_out where hbod_tran_num = hbo_tran_num and ADD_MO
NTHS(HBO_TO_MIS_DATE,24) >SYSDATE)]"
```

Comment: where is your file rr.prm ?

Comment: In the /tmp directory

Comment: i am asking the contents of this file

Comment: See my vi command following the error

Comment: escape quotes only required in command line not in a parfile. I am aware 9i is old but I have no control over that. I inherited it. Management is busy moving everything into Microsoft SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your quotes in the query.  See the documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch01.htm#1005843.

BTW, version 9i belongs in a software museum.  It was released 17 years ago and the final patch set was released over 12 years ago.

Comment: this is what it really looks like:-

Comment: query="[select * from hb_control_out_data where exists (select '1' from hb_control_out where hbod_tran_num = hbo_tran_num and ADD_MONTHS(HBO_TO_MIS_DATE,24) >SYSDATE)]"

Answer (score 0):

The error message is

> EXP-00056: ORACLE error 933 encountered
>   ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

What SQL are you executing? Well, your parameter file includes a QUERY parameter. It may be a trick of the cut'n'paste into the StackOverflow question box but this  looks odd:

```
ADD_MO NTHS(HBO_TO_MIS_DATE,24)
      ^
```

If that space or newline is not an artefact remove and re-run the export.

Comment: It is not a space. That is a cut and paste.